# Grub Boot how do I hold the screen to Indifinite

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I want to make my Grub boot screen hold to wait for someone to pick the bootable OS. I have windows and Linux mint, It does the count down from 15 seconds by default.
Also Can I edit that boot menu to only have the ubuntu or linux and windows?

Answer (score 0):

open /etc/default/grub file, replace GRUB_TIMEOUT value from **10** to **-1**. Then run

> sudo update-grub

try restarting again

Comment: thanks I ended up using customizer, I get the -1 now but I don't understand the opening /etc/default/grub file. How do you do that through terminal or through alt =f2 and when I open it its a small window that opens but I don't understand that part yet. New to Linux Mint

Comment: you can open terminal, run "gksu gedit /etc/default/grub" to open the file. Or using alt+f2 and run the same commands. both will attempt to open the file